# Where to park a car near Hirtshals (Denmark)?

Tags: automobiles, denmark

One of the options for a future trip to Iceland is to go to Hirtshals (Denmark) by car to take the ferry. This will allow us to take our own motorbikes so we don't need to rent one in Iceland. To reduce the budget, we will take the motorbikes in our car (trailer) and will take the ferry without the car, only the motorbikes.

The question is: where can we leave our car with a small trailer in the city of Hirtshals (or sorroundings) for about 15-20 days? We have though in some type of long stay parking, maybe a camping where allow to leave vehicles or even leave the cars in a public (free?) parking if Hirtshals laws allow it and cannot found other option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is some parking advice at the website of [fjordline](http://fjordline.nl/?menuid=103) (Dutch).

> Er zijn maar een beperkt aantal parkeerplaatsen bij de terminal. Wij adviseren u te parkeren in het centrum van Hirtshals.Het is ook mogelijk te parkeren bij het kortbij gelegen Hotel Skaga – Contacteer de receptie van het hotel. Het is niet mogelijk om vooruit parkeerplaatsen te boeken.

Free Translation:
There are a limited number of parking spots right at the terminal. We advise parking in the center of Hirtshals. It is also possible to park at Hotel Skaga, which is close by. Contact the reception of this hotel for further information. It is not possible to reserve parking in advance.

Comment: Hers is the official text in English http://fjordline.com/?menuid=103